# How to add A through Z at the end of a string PHP

Tags: php, concatenation, increment

What I am doing is taking a vehicle VIN number and taking the last 6 digits of it and storing it as a stock number. The issue I have is I have a function that goes and checks the database to make sure that stock number exists. If it does (can have the same vehicle in inventory again from buy back, etc) I want to concat at the end of the sting A through Z.

```
if(strlen($vin) > 9) {
    $stocknum = substr($vin,-6);
    while(verfiyUnique($mysqli, $stocknum) != true) {
        if(strlen($stocknum < 7)) {
            $stocknum = substr($vin,-6) . "A";
        }else{
            ?
        }
    }
    return $stocknum;
```

How do I increment lets say A to B or B to C if it does match?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increment the ascii number and use the `chr()` function to convert it to the relevant character. E.g.: `chr(65)` would output `A`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php for more info as well as a link to an ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `$letters = range('A','Z')` to create an array of uppercase letters and then increment an index variable to access the array. E.g.: `$letters[$i]` would output `A`

Comment: Great! Thanks for you help scoota269. I knew how to do it conceptually, but was having a brain freeze haha